# I need to disable ONLY the checkbox that is checked after i submit the form:

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, express

This is my HTML code:

Actually I have lots more check-boxes designed as buttons to select a room(which is represented by checkbox), So all of them getting selected is very annoying.

```js
$("form").submit(function() {
  $('.seat input:checkbox').prop("disabled", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form name="qwer" action="/" method="post">
  <ol class="block1">
    <li class="row row--1">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" id="1A" />
          <label for="1A">1A</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" id="1B" />
          <label for="1B">1B</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" id="1C" />
          <label for="1C">1C</label>
        </li>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

After I check the selected checkbox and submit the form, all other checkbox-es also gets disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You also have to add `:checked` to only disable the checked checkboxes.

```js
$("form").submit(function() {
  $('.seat input:checkbox:checked').prop("disabled", true); //Change here
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form name="qwer" action="/" method="post">
  <ol class="block1">
    <li class="row row--1">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" id="1A" />
          <label for="1A">1A</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" id="1B" />
          <label for="1B">1B</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" id="1C" />
          <label for="1C">1C</label>
        </li>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

Comment: @Yeshu62 If you feel the answer has helped your question, you can accept the answer so that others can also benefit. See [How to accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)